# Run cron task with python package entry_point name

Tags: python, cron, command-line-interface, python-packaging

Is there any way to run cron task with python package name (specified the in entry_point)?

**setup.py**

from setuptools import setup

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='myapp-cli',
    (..blah..)
    packages=[
        'myapp_cli'
    ],
    install_requires=['configparser', 'requests'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
              'myapp= myapp_cli.main:cli'
          ]
    },
    zip_safe=True
)
```

It works in shell:

```
myapp do_stuff
```

I want to run app by name in cron task like this:

```
* * * * * /something_here? myapp do_stuff >> myapp.log 2>&1
```

I can't figure out how python packages entry_point works and how to use it in cron. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a Python issue, but linux / shell.

The easiest way to fix it may be to use absolute paths, for Python and your script.

Assuming your entry point is located at `/usr/sbin/myapp` (you should find it with `which myapp`)

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/env python /usr/sbin/myapp do_stuff >> myapp.log 2>&1
```

Comment: And what if it gives nothing? I've checked `whereis python` returns python path, but on `whereis myapp` nothing happens.

Comment: yeah. `myapp foo` - works. `python -m myapp.main` - if you mean to execute the command in the package dir, then yes, it works as well.

Comment: I've added full setup.py file to question. Package name `myapp_cli` and entry_point is `myapp` so - `python -m myapp_cli.main` works properly (but not `python -m myapp.main` - it returns "Error while finding spec for 'myapp.main'")

Comment: I understood your idea.. `/path/to/python -m myapp_cli.main do_stuff >> ...`
That's should work (but little bit ugly ^_^)

Comment: I've found how entry_point works. Take a look at [gist](https://gist.github.com/lolorama/8766da6d61c05d5121ebfc2588d62610).

Add to your answer complete information if you want it to be accepted :)

Comment: take a look on gist. I meaned to add both `python -m` and `/path/to/python/bin/myapp` options.